# How do I save a hashmap to localstorage using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

How do I save a hashmap to localstorage using Vue?

Below is what I have right now.

Basically, it deletes an element from `this.summaries` and right after that, I assigned `localStorage.summaries` to be `this.summaries`.

My guess is that `localStorage.summaries` are not saved as hashmaps as I intended.
How can I do that?

```js
...
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.summaries) {
      this.summaries = localStorage.summaries;
    }
  },
  ...
  deleteRow(symbol) {
    delete this.summaries[symbol]
    localStorage.summaries = this.summaries
  },
...
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

...

    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="symbol in newSummaries" :key="symbol">
        ...
        <td class="border border-green-600"><button v-on:click="addRow(symbol['ticker_symbol'])">ADD</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    
...
```

Comment: I think it can be helpful to you .
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 3):

According to the ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)), the storage value is a DOMString, and it

> corresponds exactly to the JavaScript primitive String type

So if you want to save a hashmap, convert it to string with `JSON.stringify` and setItem, and when you getItem, parse it back to hashmap with `JSON.parse`

```
// set
localStorage.setItem('summaries', JSON.stringify(this.summaries))

// get
this.summaries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('summaries'))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works out fine! I guess I wanted to utilize some of what was on here https://kr.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html  but didn't work for me.

Comment: Actually further down that document does have `JSON.stringify()`. ha